# Cypress - Use Custom Command based on value

Tags: cypress

I need to write a custom command to carry out certain steps based on the element value provided through spec.ts file. I am not able to figure out how to pass the value A and B to the custom command, how to store locator value based on A or B and then using then command print the value

Spec.ts file

```
cy.writetemp(A)
cy.writetemp(B)
```

Custom Command

```
cypress.command.add(writetemp,(A) => {
cy.get("select[name='Type']").should('have.value', 'A'), then print Apple
cy.get("select[name='Type']").should('have.value', 'B'), then print Banana
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what you exactly want to achieve.

But you can define a custom command like this:

```
 Cypress.Commands.add("writeTemp", (param) => {
        if (param === "body") {
            cy.get(param).should('exist')
        } else if (param === "B") {
            cy.get("asdasd").should("contain", param);
        }
    })
```

Arguments can be passed as much as you want. Here I specified only one ("param").

Usage:

```
describe("abc", () => {
    it("get body and succeed", () => {
        cy.visit("index.html");
        cy.writeTemp("body")
    });

    it("get asdasd and fail", () => {
        cy.visit("index.html");
        cy.writeTemp("B")
    });
})
```

Let me know if I have misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to build logic based on a locator but realized that that's bad way to handle it. I switched to attribute value and it worked. thanks everyone for your time.